# Blow-ups in Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, projective-space, blowup

This is in regards to a question (no solutions or comments thus far :-() I asked earlier in regards to the blow-up of an elliptic curve: [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838106/resolution-of-singularities-base-point)

Let $f(x,y)=y^2-4x^3+ax+b$, where $(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2$. As described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719634/finding-base-points-of-a-polynomial-considered-in-projective-space), I need to consider the projective space $\mathbb{CP^2}$ to find the base point. Letting $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$, the homogeneous polynomial is $F(X,Y,Z)=Z^3\left(\frac{Y^2}{Z^2}-4\frac{X^3}{Z^3}+a\frac{X}{Z}+b\right)$. That is, $$F(X,Y,Z)=Y^2Z-4X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3.$$Solving $F(X,Y,0)=0$ yields the base point$[0,1,0]$.

I want to resolve this base point through blow-ups (I believe that there is a total of 9 blow-ups). I have no idea how to perform blow-ups in projective space. Any help (hints, books, etc.) to get me started will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay.

Comment: Dear Jay, there is a good down-to-earth explanation of the blow-up process in Chapter 2 (IIRC) of Shafarevich, _Basic Algebraic Geometry_ Volume 1.

Comment: Start with simple examples like $xy = 0$, $y^2 = x^2(x+1)$, $y^2 = x^3$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$, all blown up at the origin. Once you see what's going on, try harder examples and then come back to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is just a worked out example of a blow-up. A solution was posted by Andrew [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838106/resolution-of-singularities-base-point/845095#845095)

I will work out the blow up for the function $f(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 - x^2$. Note that $\nabla f(0,0) = 0$, so there is a singularity at $(0,0)$. If you graph the function (over $\mathbb{R}$), you will see that it crosses over itself at $(0,0)$.

Consider $f(x,xy) = x^2(y^2 -x - 1)$. Then the blow up is $g(x,y) = y^2 - x - 1$. You can look at the graph (over $\mathbb{R}$) of $g$ and see that the singularities have been resolved. Notice that $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$ is a map from $V(g) \to V(f)$. That is if I'm given a point $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y) = 0$, then it follows that $f(x,xy) = 0$. This follows from the relation $f(x,xy) = x^2g(x,y)$. Note that $x = 0$, there is something strange going on, but this is exactly the point of the blowup. It can happen that $g(0,y) \neq 0$. This map can be seen as bring the line $x=0$ to a point (and away from zero the map is a polynomial function).

To deal with points at infinity, one can work at the relevant portion of affine space.

Comment: Dear @George Shakan, Thanks for your help. To get $g(X,Z)$ are you setting $Y=1$ into $F(X,Y,Z)$ because of the base point $[0,1,0]$? Also, $g(0,0)=0$ but $\nabla g=(g_X,g_Z)=(-12X^2+aZ^2,1+2aXZ+3bZ^2)\neq (0,0)$ for $(X,Z)=(0,0)$. How is $(0,0)$ the singular point of $g$? Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Jay and George, I believe the goal of the original question is to remove the basepoint from the linear series by successive blowups, rather than to resolve a singularity of a curve.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I had completely misread the question.

Comment: Dear @ George Shakan, thank you very much for your help. Really appreciated.